# How to find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

How do I get started with this one? Variable substitution would be one way, but our lecturer hasn't covered that yet, so there should be some other way.

Usually with these kinds of limits we modify the function so that it resembles one of the standard limits that we may use without proving them.

Comment: This is a definition of $e$. There is nothing to do.

Comment: @fvel sorry to be blunt but this is nonsense (or could be replied to most any  question of this form).  It is a perfectly reasonable question to ask for an argument for the existence of this limit.

Comment: Take logarithms : you reduce to calculating $\lim_{h\to 0} \ln(1+h)/h$. Then use the definition of the derivative of $\ln$.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We only need the fact that $f(x)=e^x - 1- x >0, x\neq 0$

Firstly $e^{1/n} > 1 + \frac{1}{n}$, i.e.
$$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n < e$$

Secondly $e^{-\dfrac{1}{n+1}} > 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$, i.e.

$$\dfrac{1}{e^{\dfrac{1}{n+1}}} > 1 - \dfrac{1}{n+1}$$

thus $$e^{\dfrac{1}{n+1}} < \dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{1}{n+1}} = \dfrac{n+1}{n} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{n}$$

so $$ (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n > e^{\dfrac{n}{n+1}}$$

In summary $$ e^{\dfrac{n}{n+1}}< (1+\frac{1}{n})^n < e$$

Sending $n$ to infinity gives that the limit is equal to $e$

Comment: Big fractions as exponents look pretty weird.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yeah, it's not very beautiful, but when I use the small format it's a bit illegible, so I prefer being ugly but clear...

Comment: In this case you can write $\exp\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$.

Comment: or $e^{1/(n+1)}$

Answer (score 5):

I know of a way to do this with the use of binomial theorem. You have

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{n}+\binom{n}{2}\frac{1}{n^2}+\binom{n}{3}\frac{1}{n^3}+....$$

$$=1+1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!\cdot n^2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!\cdot n^3}+...$$

$$=1+1+\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}}{2!}+\frac{1-\frac{3}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}{3!}+...$$

Now as $n$ goes towards infinity, some terms in the numerators vanish and what remains is this:

$$\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...$$
Which we know to be $e$.

Comment: You answer is good but you can improve a little on $L_AT_EX$

Comment: I have the same amount of experience with LATEX as you. There is a post on meta version of math stack exchange which can really help you learn the basics of LATEX. I learnt it from there too. You can find it by a quick search of the website. Also, you don't recognize me?

Comment: You already do (in real life)

Answer (score 4):

It depends how you define $e$. Many texts do indeed define $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n}$ as $e,$ but to do that, it is usual to prove that the sequence is increasing, and is bounded above. Any increasing sequence of real numbers which is bounded above tends to its least upper bound. Once it is established that the limit exists, it is reasonable to give it a name, and some texts choose to define $e$ that way.

If you already know the Taylor series definition of $e$ or $e^{x}$ then it is easy to check that 
$(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(1- \frac{j}{n})$
which is always less than $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}.$ Proving the inequality the other way round (in the limit) is more difficult.

If the $\log$ function is used to define $e$ via $\log(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} dt$
and $\log (e) = 1,$ then  we have $ n \log(1 + \frac{1}{n}) < n.\frac{1}{n} =1,$ so that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} < e$ for all $n.$ On the other hand, $\log(1 + \frac{1}{n}) > \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n^{2}},$ so $n \log(1 + \frac{1}{n}) > 1 - \frac{1}{2n}$ and thus $n \log(1 + \frac{1}{n}) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

it is known that the limit exists and is $e$. here is one way show that the limit exists and is between $2$ and $3.$ we will use the facts $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ is an increasing sequence and it is bounded above by $3.$  with that the cliam will be established.

that $a_n=(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ is increasing follows from
$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \left(\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}\right)\left( \dfrac{n^2 + 2n}{n^2 + n}\right)^n > 1$ for all $n \ge 1.$
 and the boudedness follows from
$\begin{align}(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n &= 1 + 1 + \dfrac{(1-1/n)}{2} + 
\dfrac{(1-1/n)(1-2/n)}{2*3} + \dfrac{(1-1/n)(1-2/n)(1-3/n)}{2*3*4}+ \cdots\\
& \le 1 + 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2*3} + \dfrac{1}{2*3*4} + \cdots\\
& < 1 + 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2*2} + \dfrac{1}{2*2*2} + \cdots = 3\\
\end{align}$